# Set up different CORS rules based on the endpoint in Django

Tags: django, cors, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to figure out a way to have different CORS rules based on the backend endpoint frontend would hit.

So I can have

/api endpoint with a CORS domain whitelist and

/public-api without a CORS domain whitelist.

This is needed because I have both internal endpoints I use for my own frontend, and a public JS widget that can be installed in any 3rd party domain.

I've looked at **[`django-cors-headers`](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)** library, but it's regex configuration

```
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = []
```

works to let requests FROM a list of domains through.

In my case, I need to a way to have a regex (or another method) to let requests TO my endpoints through or not.

Comment: I am not sure how you do for request cors headers. But for response cors headers, you can create custom middleware and set some parameters in the view(or a decorator), and based on it custom middleware will change headers in the response. Ref for middleware https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/blob/master/src/corsheaders/middleware.py#L39

So your decorators can be like `csrf_exempt` in django.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**django-cors-headers** allows you to specify a custom handler function that will check if the request should be allowed. In your case you can use something like this:

```
# myapp/handlers.py
from corsheaders.signals import check_request_enabled

def cors_allow_particular_urls(sender, request, **kwargs):
    return request.path.startswith('/public-api/')

check_request_enabled.connect(cors_allow_mysites)
```

`handlers.py` needs to be loaded in app config:

```
# myapp/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

```
# myapp/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        # Makes sure all signal handlers are connected
        from myapp import handlers  # noqa
```

More info here: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#signals

Answer (score 2):

If you can club your private URLs under a separate prefix (ex: `/private/<something>`) you can use `CORS_URLS_REGEX=r'^/private/.*$'`

You can read more about it here:
https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_urls_regex

Comment: This is really close. However, it's a GLOBAL off switch. It does not let me respond with ALTERNATE CORS headers based on the url prefix.