# How to restrict django endpoint to localnetwork?

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

In my project, I use many FastAPI microservices to conduct the specified tasks and a Django app to handle user actions, connect with the front-end, etc.
In Django database I store information about the file paths that a microservice should obtain. I want to provide it to a microservice and this microservice only. So I want to restrict access to the endpoint to a specified port on the local network.

Other endpoints should be normally available for the web app. Using just Django cors headers will not work since I want access to most of the endpoints normally and restrict it to localhost for only a tiny subset.

```py
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://my_frontend_app" # most of the endpoints available from the front end
    "http://localhost:9877", #the microservice that I want to provide with the path
]
```

Another solution might be to use `from corsheaders.signals import check_request_enabled`, but in [the use cases that I have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010595/set-up-different-cors-rules-based-on-the-endpoint-in-django), it was usually used to broaden the access , not to restrict it (front-end should not have access to the subset of endpoints). I’m not sure whether it is a good solution.

```py
# myapp/handlers.py
from corsheaders.signals import check_request_enabled

def cors_allow_particular_urls(sender, request, **kwargs):
    return request.path.startswith('/public-api/')

check_request_enabled.connect(cors_allow_mysites)
```

Is there any way to create a “local cors”, e.g., in the form of a decorator? It would look somehow like:

```py
@local_cors([“localhost:9877”])
@decorators.action(detail=False, methods=["post"])
def get_data(self, request):
    return response.Response(status=200)
```

where `localhost:9877` is the address of a microservice

Is such a solution good enough?

```py
def get_data(self, request):
    
    request_host = request.get_host()
    data = request.data

     if request_host != MAP_UPLOAD_HOST:
        # we don't show the endpoint to the outside return       
        response.Response(status=404)
    
    return response.Response(status=200)
```

Comment: If you really only want to permit access from one caller, CORS is not sufficient: somebody could access that view some other way (possibly not even using a web browser). Does that matter?

Comment: Yeah it does. CORS is not sufficient to restrict the access?

Comment: CORS is enforced only by web browsers to prevent leaking information to unrelated pages that might request it. You need some kind of access control, either by authenticating the caller or limiting access to the URL in question.

Comment: So I should rahter limit the access to the endpoint by using somethig like
"if request.headers['Origin'] == "localhost:9877"?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the `Host` header with `get_host()` *may* offer sufficient protection, depending on your server setup.

`get_host()` will tell you the value of the `Host` header in the request, which is data provided by the client so could be manipulated in any way. The `Host` header is an integral part of HTTP 1.1 in allowing multiple domains to be hosted at a single address so you might be able to depend on your server rejecting requests that aren't actually arriving from `localhost` with a matching header, but it's difficult to be certain.

It would likely be more reliable to [check the client's network address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702217/how-to-get-a-client-ip-address-in-django-using-python) and reject requests from all clients except those that are specifically allowed.